# What other technology than flash or silverlight could block changing editing webpage via e.g. firebug in webbrowser?

Tags: security

What other technology than flash could block changing editing webpage via e.g. firebug in webbrowser?

Because everybody can change the look of the webpages and inject javascript etc. to the website.

To my knowledge only flash and silverlight can prevent this behaviour, but I might be wrong.

Do you know any other technologies used nowadays that are "uneditable" like flash or silverlight?

Comment: what makes you think flash/silverlight are uneditable? by definition anything in the user's browser can be tinkered with by the user. just because you've hidden something inside a flash movie doesn't change that.

Comment: Aren't they compiled? At least flash is or not?

Comment: You can't control what the user chooses to display on their screen. Why would you even want to do that?

Comment: @Derfder Compiled != uneditable.

Comment: What he refers to, I think, is that a flash movie is "compiled", i.e. you don't get to change behaviour in a .swf file while you can freely manipulate a 3rd party's website's DOM once it's loaded in your browser.

Comment: The reason is obvious. To offer the same experience e.g. for everybody with certain resolution etc.

Comment: @Derfder Offer them the same experience then. If people choose to change your website in Firebug, that's no concern of yours -- just make sure that the server-side components don't break when fed bad data from the web application.

Comment: The swf file is on the ftp. And if you want to decompile it you need to download it and recompile and upload back. And here is a problem. You don't have a permission to upload stuff on ftp.

Comment: @Derfder Sufficiently advanced JavaScript could fetch the SWF data, tweak it in memory, and offer it to the browser.

Comment: then you should update your question to be more explicit about what you are trying to *do*, not what you are trying to *prevent*.  Because "offer the same experience" is completely different than "block changing displayed html using developer tools"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any changes made by the user with Firebug or similar will only affect their view of the page, and will disappear as soon as they reload the page. It is not in any way a safety hazard, so just forget about it.

The only thing you should care about is validating whatever the user sends to the server, such as making sure numbers are indeed numbers, email addresses are email addresses, and so on.

Comment: This is not true if you use ajax etc.

Comment: Huh? What does that have to do with it?

Comment: "Any changes made by the user with Firebug or similar will only affect their view of the page" not true if you are using some javascript stuff

Comment: @Derfder you cannot trust that code in the browser will always send appropriate requests to your server. You need code in the server that validates all HTTP transactions, so that any AJAX calls that try anything improper will be rejected.

Comment: I know that, but some javascript injections can break something, you never know

Comment: It would only break on their view of the page, and if they modified the page to break it that's their own problem.

Comment: So, except flash there is no other way how to do that?

Comment: @Derfder The point is that if your server code is properly validating things, the only thing a user can do is break *their view* of the page, and *not anybody else's*.  If someone is fiddling with their view of the page in Firebug, *it's their problem, not yours*.  **Using Flash does not absolve you from the need for having proper server-side validation of user input.**

Comment: hmm, ok I just wanted to know if it is possible to elminated such "hacker-ish"user behaviour, but it seems that it is not possible.

Comment: @Derfder It's not possible. Even if you used Flash, someone could run a packet sniffer and see what data the application is sending to the server. Then they could craft their own requests using a completely different programming language and try to attack your server. *Anything your application can do, a sufficiently advanced user can try to break.*

Comment: Er no. _Including_ flash, there's no way to stop it. 5 words - sothink swf decompiler, local (swf) copy.